# Перенаправить на другую страницу

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Уважаемые подскажите пожалуйста. Есть у меня asp.net webApi 2 application. В нем у меня  authorizationFilter: AuthorizationFilterAttribute. Переопределяю я метод onAuthorizationAsync. В нем я запрашиваю текущие права пользователя. Вопрос такой: как мне отсюда перенаправить пользователя на другую страницу (например page.html) если у него недостаточно прав ? Это можно вроде как то сделать с помощью HttpActionContext в response передать HttpResponseMessage но у меня не получается отправить именно на page.html(находится в папке с проектом).

Comment: `Response.Redirect(url)` не подходит, что ли?

Comment: Поидее подходит, но я не совсем понимаю какой маршрут указывать. Index.html находится в client/app рядом с ним и page.html